# Downgrade from php 5.5 to php 5.4 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Hello guys i have a php code that is running on the version 5.4 so i cannot use the version 5.5 i read alot of threads but nobody seems to solved me the problem can anyone help? thanks in adanvance

when i do `php -v` this is what i get

```
PHP 5.5.34-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)  
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

i am really getting crazy i dunno how to get it since i read that php  is not supporting the 5.4 version  any more

Comment: did you read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/498175/how-to-downgrade-php-from-5-5-9-to-5-4-in-ubuntu-14-04-installed-with-lamp?

Comment: Yes the problem is that it wont give me the error like it should `Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://php53.dotdeb.org stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY xxxxxCODExxxx`

Comment: its just simple says the package is not there  DDDDDD: